# Filtering a WP_Query meta_query values date isn't working

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

When I use the acf plugin is normal, but when using acf pro plugin does not working ???

```
 $wp_query_post = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'meta_query' =>
        array(
            array(
                'key'        => 'timestart',
                'compare'    => '<=',
                'meta_type' => 'DATE',
                'value'      => $datetime,
                ),
            'relation'   => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'        => 'timeend',
                'compare'    => '>=',
                'meta_type' => 'DATE',
                'value'      => $datetime,
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert strtotime and try like below,

```
$wp_query_post = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'meta_query' =>
    array(
        array(
            'key'        => 'timestart',
            'compare'    => '<=',
            'meta_type' => 'DATE',
            'value'      => intval(strtotime($datetime)),
            ),
        'relation'   => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'        => 'timeend',
            'compare'    => '>=',
            'meta_type' => 'DATE',
            'value'      => intval(strtotime($datetime)),
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably have done this already, but make sure the format of *$datetime* matches the format of the custom fields, *timestart* and *timeend*.

You may also need to change meta_type, depending on the time format:

```
'meta_type' => 'DATETIME'
```